# Animate hundreds of markers with Google Map on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, marker

I have more then 300 markers on top of Google Map in my Android project. They are vehicles in San Francisco as you can see from the screenshot.
I have direction and speed of the vehicles and I want to animate them for 10 seconds before the next call to the API.

To animate one marker I use this code:

```
static void animateMarkerToICS(Marker marker, LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
    TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
        @Override
        public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
            return latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
        }
    };
    Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);

    animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    animator.setDuration(ANIMATION_MILLIS);
    animator.start();
}
```

When I call this for all 300 marker the map is, as expected, slow and not very responsive.

The question is, what is the best way to animate 300 markers at the same time?
Is there an efficient way to achieve good performance for this task?

(I'm using Google Maps v2 on Android > 4.0)

p.s. I'm not planning to run the animation when the map if fully zoomed out so probably I will never have all 300 markers moving at the same time but still I would like to have feedback about the best way to work on this problem. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Animating just a single marker like that, creates thousands of internal objects per second =(

Comment: @robsf Can you please help me with how you are calling this method and which values you are passing in it. This is my code : http://pastebin.com/yQZEZsf2

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [asynchronous task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?
This will take the emphasis off your main UI thread and throw the "computation" to the background. Thus making your map more responsive and not lag.

This is something I would possibly consider....

1. Create a Asynch Class.
2. In the Do background method put your marker calculation method etc.

   ```
   protected String doInBackground(Location... params) {
     // Show user a Progress bar/Dialog    
     // your markers plotting function here... 
   }
   ```
3. In the post post execute function revert back to the map

   ```
   protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
    // Revert back to map
   }
   ```

#### Note I am assuming you already have the Lat/Lng  coordinates for the 300 markers and only plotting them takes forever. If however you don't have the coordinates you can create a Asych task for that aswell and free up your main thread.

Comment: Positions are loaded asynchronously already and the animation code is called from a background task already. That's not the issue. Thanks.